# re-arrange div boxes after certain breakpoint

Tags: html, css

my layout has an odd section with an image at left side and some copy text on the right side. The following section (even) is with the copy on the left side and the image is on the right side (and so on ...)

Now, after the breakpoint (for mobile) i want the text to be first and then the image … and so on … How can I flip the div boxes (so that the image is always AFTER the copy div box? How can I manage this with CSS?

So far, i could manage that after the breakpoint every div is 100% percent, but like that the arrangement stays the same off course ...

Thank you very much for the help!

Here's my code:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#wrap {max-width: 960px; height: 2120px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: gray;}

.even {background-color: orange;}

.odd {background-color: skyblue;}

.pic, .copy {height: 200px; margin: 4% 3%;}

.copy {background-color: pink;}

@media screen and (min-width:320px) {.pic, .copy {width: 100%;}}

@media screen and (min-width:668px) {.pic, .copy {width: 44%; float: left;}}

<div id="wrap">
  <section class="odd">
    <div class="pic">IMAGE</div>
    <div class="copy">TEXT</div>
  </section>
  <section class="even">
    <div class="copy">TEXT</div>
    <div class="pic">IMAGE</div>
  </section>
  <section class="odd">
    <div class="pic">IMAGE</div>
    <div class="copy">TEXT</div>
  </section>
  <section class="even">
    <div class="copy">TEXT</div>
    <div class="pic">IMAGE</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox....just do it!

Comment: case1: a float:left; b float-right. Case2: a float-right; b float-left; ya?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix: http://codepen.io/gilalberto/pen/pyRBwQ

I changed the HTML to be on the desired order for mobile (copy and then the image) and for desktop, I added the rule:

```
@media screen and (min-width:668px) {
  .odd .copy {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

So, in odd will move the text to the right.

Also I added a clearfix for the floats, there is a link and comments in the codepen.

Try to make the HTML, CSS and JS work first for mobile, then do the changes with media query or JS for desktop. Mobile-first development, will come real handy when developing responsive designs http://zellwk.com/blog/how-to-write-mobile-first-css/

Comment: You can also do it with flex, like Paulie_D mentioned, you can read more in https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you gilalberto!

Comment: You're welcome ;) , remember to mark it as resolved.